Bike squeaking when pedaling
Over the last couple of days my bike has developed a constant squeak when pedalling, which is annoying and sounds unhealthy. I've added some Fenwick all weather chain lube to the chain, but it's made no difference. Does anyone have any ideas as to what else might be causing this please?
Here's what I've found so far:

The noise happens whether I'm sitting or standing, but only when I'm actively pedalling; there's no noise when coasting

The noise is constant when pedalling; there doesn't seem to be a specific position it happens in

The noise gets stronger the more force I apply to the right pedal (i.e., the chainring side)

The noise doesn't happen if I hold the back wheel off the ground and turn the pedals, so it's difficult to pinpoint specifically where it's coming from

It doesn't feel like there's any extra resistance when pedaling


The bike is a Cannondale Quick 6. I only got it a year ago.
Thanks in advance for any advice!
EDIT: Adding a picture of the chainring bolts in response to a comment:


Based on the description it's in the drivetrain. Does it make more or less noise on the left pedal or right pedal? Probably on the down stroke? Does it seem to be coming from the rear or the crank area?

It's louder when I put more force on the right pedal then it is when I put more force on the left pedal. It feels like it's coming from the crank area.

Loose pedal or loose crank arm would be worth a check. Even though it's a new bike sometimes things are missed in assembly.

Pedals, crank arms and then make sure the QR-skewers are tight! If no luck, check for play in the BB. If no luck, be happy and check the rest of endless possibilities.

Do you have temporary access to Rollers and an assistant ?  Sometimes, listening from the side while someone pedals, can be helpful in triangulating the source region

@DavidD I've tried tightening the crank arms and pedals, but no luck. I've also tried holding the pedals and wiggling the crank arms from side to side (i.e. 90 degrees to the bike) to check for looseness and there doesn't seem to be any.

@WornChain Seems like all of those things are tight, with no wiggle room...

@Criggie Unfortunately not

Lubricate the jockey wheels on the derailleur. It could also be the freehub bearing, which only turns when you are pedalling.

As deducted in the question and comments, the squeak is most likely from the drivetrain since it is only present when pedaling both in and out of the saddle.
Having the sound on both pedal strokes would to me indicate either BB or chainring bolts, since the chain is properly lubed.
My checklist for squeaks in the crank area:

pedals are tight, bearings are smooth (change pedals to rule out pedal squeak).
crankarms are tight with no play on the axle.
chainring bolts are tight.
crankset has little to no sideways play.
bottom bracket has smooth bearings and is seated correctly in the bracket shell (I've had some threaded BBs loosening up on me).

My current bike developed a similar squeak which turned out to be under-tightened chainring bolts. I had to put a dab of thread locker on them in the end, as the squeak reappeared after a ride or two if I only tightened them.

No, this is definitely a good answer.  Welcome to the site !

@Nordic Biker Thanks! I've tightened the pedals and crankarms with no luck (both seemed tight already; no sideways play in the crankset). I'll check the bearings when I can. I have a daft question though - what are my chainring bolts? I've added a picture of the chainring to my original post so you can see what I'm looking at. The screws on the largest chainring I've already tightened; are the circular bolt-y rivet-y things on the middle and small chainring what you mean? And if so how do I tighten them since an allan key or screwdriver won't fit - do I need a special tool?

@SRJCoding turns out, your bike has rivetted chainrings to the crank-spider.   There are no chainring bolts in your photo.  So these are unlikely to be the cause of your noise.

Oh, rivets! They should be maintenance free and good for the lifetime of the chainrings. I guess the screws on the big ring only attach to the plastic chainguard on the outside, and should not cause a squeak either. The chain is a bit dirty, but this usually causes more of a slight crunching sound (if any noise at all) rather than a squeak.
